# Polars searchsorted with a Series

Tags: python-polars

`searchsorted` is an incredibly useful utility in `numpy` and `pandas` for performing a binary search on every element in a list, especially for time-series data.

```py
import numpy as np

np.searchsorted(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']) # Returns [0, 2, 3]
np.searchsorted(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], side='right') # Returns [2, 3, 4]
```

I have a few questions about Polars

1. Is there any way to apply `search_sorted` on a list in polars in a vectorized manner?
2. Is there any way to specify `side=right` for `search_sorted`?
3. Can we use non-numeric data in `search_sorted`?
4. If answer is no to the questions, what would be the recommended approach / workaround to achieve the functionalities?

   - (The ideal approach is if `search_sorted` can be used as part of an expression, e.g. `pl.col('A').search_sorted(pl.col('B))`)

Here's what I have tried:

```py
import polars as pl

pl.Series(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']).search_sorted(['a', 'b', 'c']) # PanicException: not implemented for Utf8

pl.Series([0, 0, 1, 2]).search_sorted([0, 1, 2]) # PanicException: dtype List not implemented

list(map(pl.Series([0, 0, 1, 2]).search_sorted, [0, 1, 2])) # Returns [1, 2, 3], different from numpy results

pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [0, 0, 1, 2],
    'b': [0, 1, 2, 3],
}).with_columns([
    pl.col('a').search_sorted(pl.col('b')).alias('c')
]) # Column C is [1, 1, 1, 1], which is incorrect
```

I understand Polars is still a work in progress and some functionalities are missing, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend on @ritchie46's answer, you need a rolling join so that missing values can be joined to their near neighbor.  Unfortunately rolling joins don't work on letters, or more accurately `Utf8` dtypes so for your example you have to do an extra step.

Starting from:

```
df1 = (pl.Series("a", ["a", "a", "b", "c"])
    .set_sorted()
    .to_frame()
    .with_row_count("idx"))

df2 = pl.Series("a", ["a", "b", "c"]).set_sorted().to_frame()
```

then we make a df to house all the possible values of `a` and map them to a numeric.

```
dfindx=(pl.DataFrame(pl.concat([df1.get_column('a'),df2.get_column('a')]).unique())
        .sort('a').with_row_count('valindx'))
```

now we add that `valindx` to each of `df1` and `df2`

```
df1=df1.join(dfindx, on='a')
df2=df2.join(dfindx, on='a')
```

To get almost to the finish line you'd do:

```
df2.join_asof(df1, on='valindx', strategy='forward')
```

this will leave missing the last value, the `4` from the numpy case because essentially what's happening is that the first value 'a' doesn't find a match but its nearest forward neighbor is a 'b' so it takes that value and so on but when it gets to 'e' there is nothing in df1 forward of that so we need to do a minor hack of just filling in that null with the max idx+1.

```
(df2.
    join_asof(df1, on='valindx', strategy='forward')
    .with_column(pl.col('idx').fill_null(df1.select(pl.col('idx').max()+1)[0,0]))
    .get_column('idx'))
```

Of course, if you're using time or numerics then you can skip the first step.  Additionally, I suspect that fetching this index value is an intermediate step and that overall process would be done more efficiently without extracting the index values at all but that would be through a `join_asof`.

If you change the `strategy` of `join_asof` then that should be largely the same as switching the `side` but you'd have to change the hack bit at the end too.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I added the requested functionality and it will be available in next release: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/6083

### Old answer (wrong)

For a "normal" search sorted we can use a `join`.

```py
# convert to DataFrame 
# provide polars with the information the data is sorted (this speeds up many algorithms)
# set a row count
df1 = (pl.Series("a", ["a", "a", "b", "c"])
       .set_sorted()
       .to_frame()
       .with_row_count("idx"))

df2 = pl.Series("a", ["a", "b", "c"]).set_sorted().to_frame()

# join
# drop duplicates
# and only show the indices that were joined
df1.join(df2, on="a", how="semi").unique(subset=["a"])["idx"]
```

```
Series: 'idx' [u32]
[
    0
    2
    3
]
```

Comment: That wouldn't work if the elements in df2 are not in df1, e.g. `df1 = ['b', 'b', 'd', 'd']`, `df2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`. numpy would return `[0, 2, 2, 4, 4]` while this approach return `[0, 2]`

Comment: I added the functionality in polars: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/6083