# Is it possible to disallow exact matches on join_asof?

Tags: python-polars

In pandas, we can disallow exact matches in `merge_asof` by passing `allow_exact_matches=False`, as seen in the examples in the [pandas merge_asof docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html). Is this possible in polars, and if not is there an alternative solution?

This option doesn't seem to be present in the [polars join_asof docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join_asof.html).

EDIT: Some pandas examples

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 3, 5, 7],
    "b": [1, 3, 5, 7]
})


(pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on="a", direction='forward', allow_exact_matches=False))
# column b is [3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, None]

(pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on="a", direction='backward', allow_exact_matches=False))
# column b is [None, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first filter exact matches using `anti` join.

```py
df1 = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
})

df2 = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 3, 5, 7],
    "b": [1, 3, 5, 7]
})


(df1
 .join(df2, on="a", how="anti")
 .join_asof(df2, on="a")
)
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 1   │
│ 4   ┆ 3   │
│ 6   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Is that going to be better than just filtering out the equalities after a single join? ie. `df1.join_asof(df2.with_column(pl.col('a').alias('a_right')), on = "a").filter(pl.col('a')!=pl.col('a_right')).select(pl.exclude('a_right'))`.

Comment: Would it be possible to preserve the shape of `df1`, i.e. a left join?

In pandas, it would look something like this

`(pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on="a", direction='forward', allow_exact_matches=False)) # [3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, None]`

`(pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on="a", direction='backward', allow_exact_matches=False)) # [None, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5]`

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I am not sure regarding the performance vs the filter afterwards.

Comment: @T.HRice you can just add/subtract 1 from df2's 'a' column (assuming integer, if a float then you'd have to add/subtract a value smaller than the smallest difference).  For instance `df1.join_asof(df2.with_column(pl.col('a')+1), on = "a")` or `df1.join_asof(df2.with_column(pl.col('a')-1), on = "a", strategy='forward')`

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I see, that’s not so ideal as it is type dependent (wouldn’t work on utf8s for example) but that’s definitely a fast workaround. Thanks!

Comment: @T.HRice well join_asof doesn't work on utf8 anyway, at least not yet.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor ah you’re right, it doesn’t work it pandas as well. That’s interesting

Comment: You can check out this answer with a work around for a join_asof on utf8 https://stackoverflow.com/a/75020475/1818713